# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class in OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm trying to upload an image to my server using flask back end which will handle the file to save in a folder and OkHttp in android. but I get this error in android:

```
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$configureTrustManager$1>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/conscrypt/ConscryptHostnameVerifier;
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.SocketAdapter okhttp3.internal.platform.android.ConscryptSocketAdapter.buildIfSupported() (ConscryptSocketAdapter.kt:64)
        at void okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.<init>() (AndroidPlatform.kt:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$Companion.buildIfSupported() (AndroidPlatform.kt:239)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.findPlatform() (Platform.kt:211)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.access$findPlatform(okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion) (Platform.kt:179)
        at void okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>() (Platform.kt:180)
        at void okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder) (OkHttpClient.kt:219)
        at void okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>() (OkHttpClient.kt:211)
        at void com.example.swiftpinx.Activity.AddMediaActivity.onClick(android.view.View) (AddMediaActivity.java:207)
        at boolean android.view.View.performClick() (View.java:5637)
        at void android.view.View$PerformClick.run() (View.java:22429)
        at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:751)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:95)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.swiftpinx-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.swiftpinx-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.SocketAdapter okhttp3.internal.platform.android.ConscryptSocketAdapter.buildIfSupported() (ConscryptSocketAdapter.kt:64)
        at void okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.<init>() (AndroidPlatform.kt:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$Companion.buildIfSupported() (AndroidPlatform.kt:239)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.findPlatform() (Platform.kt:211)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.access$findPlatform(okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion) (Platform.kt:179)
        at void okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>() (Platform.kt:180)
        at void okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder) (OkHttpClient.kt:219)
        at void okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>() (OkHttpClient.kt:211)
        at void com.example.swiftpinx.Activity.AddMediaActivity.onClick(android.view.View) (AddMediaActivity.java:207)
        at boolean android.view.View.performClick() (View.java:5637)
        at void android.view.View$PerformClick.run() (View.java:22429)
        at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:751)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:95)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

And trying to find a solution online to fix this issue and yet nothing solve on my situation.

maybe you might need my source code, here:

```
package com.example.swiftpinx.Activity;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder;
import com.example.swiftpinx.Adapters.AddMediaAdapter;
import com.example.swiftpinx.Link.UrlLink;
import com.example.swiftpinx.R;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class AddMediaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, AddMediaAdapter.OnClickThumbnail,
        View.OnClickListener {

    /*
        Set up's
     */

    private static final String TAG = "AddMediaActivity";

    private final static int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    private final static int MEDIASTORE_LOADER_ID = 0;

    AddMediaAdapter addMediaAdapter;

    Uri imagePath;

    /*
        Pallete
     */

    RecyclerView rvGallery;

    ImageView ivImage;

    LinearLayout llPostEvent;

    Button btnPost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_media);

        rvGallery = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvGallery);
        rvGallery.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));

        addMediaAdapter = new AddMediaAdapter(this);

        rvGallery.setAdapter(addMediaAdapter);

        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

        llPostEvent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llPostEvent);

        btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);

        btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);

        llPostEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        checkPermissionEnternalStorage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(MEDIASTORE_LOADER_ID, null, this);
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }
    }

    private void checkPermissionEnternalStorage() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(MEDIASTORE_LOADER_ID, null, this);
            } else {
                if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    // explain here.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Swiftpin wants to view your gallery.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                        READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        } else {
            // load default
            LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(MEDIASTORE_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE
        };

        String condition = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE + " OR "
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

        return new CursorLoader(
                this,
                MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
                projection,
                condition,
                null,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        addMediaAdapter.changeCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        addMediaAdapter.changeCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void clickThumbnail(Uri uri) {
        imagePath = uri;
        llPostEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load("file://" + uri)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(ivImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == btnPost) {
            String fileImage = String.valueOf(imagePath);

            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileImage, options);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("image", "image.jpg",
                                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*jpg"), byteArray))
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(UrlLink.postfeed)
                        .post(requestBody)
                        .build();

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                        call.cancel();

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.i(TAG, "run: Error post");
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "run: ok -> " + response.body().toString());
                                } catch(Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OkHttp version? Device? This looks like an OkHttp bug.

Comment: did u found any solution???

Answer (score 53, accepted):

While reading the info message, it gives me an idea about this `Conscrypt` and did a research and found out that I need to install `conscrypt` to my gradle.app

```
implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.2.1'
```

and it works.

Comment: If okHttp needs `conscrypt`, it should reference this library instead of forcing us to add this dependency.

This should not be marked as accepted. Better file a bug report on square's github repo.

Comment: @kroegerama well okhttp doesn't *need* conscrypt, it's an optional dependency that it's compatible with. The error message can definitely be improved, but the library will use your system's default implementation if conscrypt is not included, and is compatible with conscrypt if you explicitly set it as the first security provider. See okhttp's README for more information.

Regardless, I agree that this shouldn't be the accepted answer, because the warning is probably safe to ignore, and it's a bad idea to unnecessarily add dependencies to your project.

Answer (score 15):

OkHttp is compatible with the Conscrypt security library, but using it is optional. The stack trace is scary, but I think it is just a warning telling you that the Conscrypt dependency was not found. In this case, OkHttp should fall back to your platform's default TLS implementation.

From [OkHttp's README](https://github.com/square/okhttp#requirements):

> OkHttp uses your platform's built-in TLS implementation. On Java platforms OkHttp also supports Conscrypt, which integrates BoringSSL with Java. OkHttp will use Conscrypt if it is the first security provider:
>
> `Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);`

So long story short, if your network requests are working, it is probably safe to ignore this stack trace.